# Magento2: How can I format the price with two decimal places in the admin ui form field?

Tags: price, adminform, magento2.3.2, ui-form, format

In **Magento version 2.3.2 and 2.3.3**, in a **UI form**, I have a field element **input**, of type **price***:

```
<field formElement="input" name="price" sortOrder="60">
    <settings>
        <dataType>price</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Price</label>
        <dataScope>price</dataScope>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-medium">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

[Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-input.html), I found documentation for field types, from UI form.

I want the price in that field to be displayed with two decimal places, “10.00” instead of “10.0000”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to format the price, from a field in **UI form**, it is necessary to extend the component `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` that has actions on the elements of a **UI form** - in our case we overwrite the `setInitialValue` method from `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` in our component.

To format the price, we will use another component in our `Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils` component which deals with the formatting of the price, with the `formatPrice` method.

The component for price formatting is created in the module developed in `view/adminhtml/web/js/format-price.js` which contains the following code:

```
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
  'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function (Element, priceUtils) {
  'use strict';

  return Element.extend({
    defaults: {
      'defaultText': '',
    },
    setInitialValue: function() {
      this._super();
      var self = this;

      self.setFormatPrice(self.initialValue);
      return this;
    },

    setFormatPrice: function(value) {
      var price = (value) ? priceUtils.formatPrice(value) : this.defaultText;
      this.initialValue = price;
      this.value._latestValue = price;

      return this;
    }
  });
});
```

In the file where you declared the field in the **UI form**, it is necessary to call your component `VendorName_ModuleName/js/format-price` and specify the method used to set the value in the field `setInitialValue`, see below:

```
<field formElement="input" name="price" component="VendorName_ModuleName/js/format-price" sortOrder="60">
    <settings>
        <dataType>price</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Price</label>
        <dataScope>price</dataScope>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-medium">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <imports>
            <link name="setInitialValue" />
        </imports>
    </settings>
</field>
```

See the result from screenshot:

[image]